# Why is OnDragEnter not called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have added the COleDropTarget variable to my view class and registered it in the OnCreate(), which is being called at startup. I added the OnDragEnter and OnDrop virtual functions (not the others yet, as OnDragLeave). But they are not called when I drag (or drop) a piece of text over them.

I just happened to think about the fact that I had already implemented the dropfiles function to the same window. Is this preventing the text drag?

What else do I need?

TIA,

Harvey

Comment: I tried commenting out the code for dropfiles, but still OnDragEnter is never called. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

In using F1 to get the syntax for OnDrop and the others, MSDN gave me:

```
virtual BOOL OnDrop(
   CWnd* pWnd,
   COleDataObject* pDataObject,
   DROPEFFECT dropEffect,
   CPoint point 
);
```

But the correct virtual function does not have the first parameter and should be:

```
virtual BOOL OnDrop(
   COleDataObject* pDataObject,
   DROPEFFECT dropEffect,
   CPoint point 
);
```

Same with the others. So I was never actually overriding the default functions.